# ruby picture download verification

Tags: ruby, jpeg, open-uri

I would like to know if it is possible to check if a picture downloaded using open-uri () was downloaded correctly?

There are 2 cases I would like to manage:
1. the picture is at least 80% black (in this case, it is an error)
2. the picture is simply unreadable by picture reader (ex: Ephoto on Linux)

Ideally, the code would look somewhat like this

```
pic_buffer = open(my_link, "User-Agent" => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}")
if functionCheckPictureDownloadedCorrectly(pic_buffer) == false
  abort("file is unreadable")
end
puts "file is good, saving it"
File.open(name_buffer + ".jpg", 'wb') do |pic|
  pic << pic_buffer.read
end
```

Note : I am only downloading .jpeg pictures

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage as it might be what you want.

Comment: thanks for the tip ^^, it does seem to be able to do a few tests, any idea on how to check the color of the picture ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489257/how-do-i-get-the-hex-value-from-each-pixel-in-rmagick-or-chunky-png/35489589#35489589 might help

Comment: thanks for the tip ^^